# How to denote $h(\theta)$ and $h_\theta(x)$ verbally - Is there a difference?

Tags: notation, self-learning

This is a very newb question but I'm having trouble with understanding the notation between the two. How should I be saying it in my head?
$h(\theta)$ vs $h_\theta(x)$

The first one is the function $h$ with respect to $\theta$.
Is the second one, the function $h$ with respect to $x$ at each iteration of $\theta$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: One way of saying it is 'h of theta' vs 'h sub theta of x'. I'm not sure if it matters, as long as you are consistent.